# Transpose rows to column python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this

```
                         Column1  Column2    Column3
0  This Sushi is Awesome          NaN        NaN
1  NaN                            Id:        2261
2  NaN                            City:      Tokyo
3  NaN                            Food:      Positive
4  NaN                            Price:     NaN
5  This food is really expensi... NaN        NaN
6  NaN                            Id:        3`
7  NaN                            City:      Osaka
8  NaN                            Food:      Negative
9  NaN                            Price:     Negative
```

i wrote code like this but i got error

```
pivoted = data.pivot(index='Column1',columns='Column2', values='Column3')
```

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

pivot_table also doesnt work

I want to have output like this

```
0                                 Id         City      Food      Price
1  This Sushi is Awesome          2261       Tokyo     Positive  NaN
2  This food is really expensi... 3          Osaka     Negative  Negative
```

Comment: Use ffill on Column1, then look at SO post on "How to pivot a dataframe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pre processing before `pivot` - check missing values per `Column1`, then forward fillling, remove `:` from `Column2` by [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['Column1'].isnull()
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].ffill()
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.rstrip(':')

pivoted = df[m].pivot(index='Column1',columns='Column2', values='Column3')
print (pivoted)
Column2                         City      Food    Id     Price
Column1                                                       
This Sushi is Awesome          Tokyo  Positive  2261       NaN
This food is really expensive  Osaka  Negative    3`  Negative
```

Comment: Damn I was trying :P